# remove grey background on link clicked in ios safari / chrome / firefox

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

When you click (touch) a link in Safari (or chrome or firefox)  for iOS, you get a grey background behind link (only while you're holding it). Is there a way to remove this feature using CSS?

Please see the example image below:

[image]

Comment: I have not really an idea about safari iOS, but when you are talking about links and css, then I guess you best change the background-color in a:active

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Webkit has a specific style property for that: `-webkit-tap-highlight-color`.

Copied from: http://davidwalsh.name/mobile-highlight-color—

```
/* light blue at 80% opacity */
html {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(201, 224, 253, 0.8);
}

/* change it for a div that has a similar background-color to the light blue tap color */
.blueDiv {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(251, 185, 250, 0.9);
}
```

If you want to remove the highlight completely—

```
.myButton {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Amazing, fixed my iOS tap background issue

Answer (score 19):

Latest versions of iOS are ignoring RGBA colors for some reason.

To remove it, I ended up having to use the following:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

As documented here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color