# Mobile Safari sometimes does not trigger the click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile-safari, dom-events

This is a dynamic JavaScript application I am working on. I have many `<a>` anchor elements that have a class. When that class is clicked, something should happen. This works fine in Firefox, Chrome, IE, but **in some cases** the click event is not triggered on mobile Safari (iPad and iPhone).

These elements all have exactly the same CSS, it's just their position that differs (they are in different containers).

I tried various solutions that I found here but with no luck. For instance:

- setting the cursor to pointer
- the code [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805608/how-to-set-the-click-event-in-a-global-way-for-safari)

Do you have any other idea that might help me find a solution to this? Why does the click event triggers only in some cases?

Comment: You should have an href attribute to ensure the anchor works properly. Use .preventDefault() in js to counter its behavior.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Added hrefs but no luck. The other elements that work also didn't have hrefs. How exactly should I use the .preventDefault()?

Comment: The application uses jQuery, so there is .preventDefault() in its click function.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The click event resulting from a tap on iOS will bubble as expected under just certain conditions -- one of which you mentioned, the cursor style. Here is another:

> The target element, or any of its ancestors up to but not including
>   the `<body>`, has an explicit event handler set for any of the mouse
>   events. This event handler may be an empty function.

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2014/02/mouse_event_bub.html

This is much better fix vector, and can be done without a browser check. You do have to add an extra div due to the "not including the `<body>`" part:

```
<body>
  <div onclick="void(0);">
    <!-- ... all your normal body content ... -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Now every click event originating inside that div will bubble as expected in iOS (meaning you can catch them with `$(document).on('click', '.class', etc...)`).

Comment: I'd choose `body { cursor:pointer; }`. Many codes insert dynamic elements to `body`, I don't want to have to modify them all.

Comment: @deerchao it cannot have side effects on other browsers ? because this simple CSS statement works ! :)

Comment: 3 years later this is still a solution to this for Safari on mobile. Everything worked on Chrome and Firefox, but Safari we had to add this to the parent containers of only a few that weren't firing right, preferred an isolated approach.

Comment: I ran into this bug in React with material-ui, and adding a dummy `onClick={function(){}}` allowed the mouseleave event to be properly called on my element. This is insanity, but it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried this?? This is because ios doesn't fire the click event sometimes, only recognizes the touch event

```
$(document).on('touchstart click', [Selector], [ Event ]
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like adding the touchstart event works. However, it  might not be the best solution as the action gets triggered even if the user simply tries to scroll and starts having his finger on that link. Is there any better way than using `touchstart`?

Comment: For me this ends up triggering twice, and where i have a toggle my popup shows for a split second and hides again.

Answer (score 7):

Just declaring these empty event listeners does the trick. Just try it :)

This will make it work on all browsers:

```
container.addEventListener('touchstart', () => {});
container.addEventListener('touchend', () => {});
container.addEventListener('touchcancel', () => {});
container.addEventListener('touchmove', () => {});
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you expand on why this works? Because it works well!

Answer (score 5):

There is an additional event for mobile devices. Try to add the `tap` event listener in addition to the `click` event.  They can be attached simultaneously with the following:

```js
$(document).on('click tap', [selector], [handler])
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess you meant `tap`. I tried most events with no outcome.

Comment: maybe it would help to post the structur, so one can see the DOM. Maybe the Event ist captured elsewhere and not bubbled through

Answer (score 2):

For me the behaviour was random. Everything worked fine, but after some changes really random problems with firing the click event of some buttons occured.

The problem was button hover with some mobile devices (Atleast some iOS iPads with Safari for me)
And I fixed it with adding @media hover and pointer addition to all my hoverings:

```
@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {
    .topnav a:hover {
        background-color: lightcoral;
    }
}
```

This writing help me to figure this out (even I don't use react here) https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7635#issuecomment-365089006

Answer (score 2):

Just spent an hour debugging another crazy scenario where Safari swallows taps as none of the tips above helped and the issue appeared seemingly out of nowhere.

tl;dr: if underlying CSS causes reflow on hover, bubbling won't reach the element where reflow happens.

Consider the following markup:

```html
container
  div 
    span
```

```js
    container.addEventListener('click', MouseClick, false)
```

```css
span {opacity: 0;} 

div:hover {
    span {opacity: 1;}
 }
```

As a result, in mobile Safari on tap the `div` element won't receive a `click` event due to the fact that the first tap equals hover-like event and this triggers CSS reflow on the `span` (which is much smaller than div and is OUTSIDE of tap target coordinates). At the same time, there're other css hover events happening within the same div which does not cause lost clicks.

I was mindblown when narrowed this down to this CSS.. luckily it was added to codebase yesterday and was easy to track down, but holy web, Safari truly sucks to develop for.

Answer (score 1):

This is a crazy issue and indeed [LinusR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39712411/1248175) and the [description on quirksmode](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2014/02/mouse_event_bub.html) are accurate. My general click event listener didn't work because of this in iOS Safari:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    alert("Where's my click?!");
});
```

I now have wrapped my app with a `<div onclick="void(0);"></div>` and that works. I also added some extra things to fix some issues that came out of it:

```
<div onclick="void(0);" style="height: 100%; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;">
  <div style="height: 100%; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: initial;">
    <my-app></my-app>
  </div>
</div>
```

I needed the `height: 100%;` to make the click available on the whole page because I needed that. If you don't do `height: 100%;` the click event will still only fire within the height of the div.

The `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;` is to prevent an onclick flash overlay style, as iOS does this by default with clickable elements. The div after that restores the initial value of that CSS property, so that other clickable elements do have normal behavior in this regard. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11885330/1248175) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the button had a `:hover/:focus` with a size changing property like border: 3px.

The small size change was enough to reflow the position and void the click.

It happened on mobile just because the space was limited.

Answer (score 0):

This is mindblowing but what Benny K posted about underlying CSS causing reflow on hover fixed my issue!

I removed the following two tags from my CSS and it magically worked:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
```

I'm still shocked but happy that it fixed the issue. Hope this helps someone else too.