# Transparent buttons and active states in a mobile

Tags: html, css

I made a transparent button:

```css
.home-btn-left {
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a class="home-btn-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮</a>
```

It doesn't have a hover, focus or active state. But when I push it on my iphone I see this and I really don't wanna have it:

[image]

Do you have some suggestion?

https://jsfiddle.net/3bfptxty/

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ add your code there so people can see what is happening and what can be changed to get the right result.

Comment: Yeah, just add your code to jsfiddle.net so we can edit it

Comment: maybe you should apply class name to the button as it called in css-rules: `<a class="home-btn-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should apply the styles for every state of the `<a>` element using:

```
.home-btn-left,.home-btn-left:hover,
.home-btn-left:active, .home-btn-left:focus { /* your styles */ }
```

then you should add the otline property, to prevent dotted outline or similar behaviours

```
outline: 0;
```

Edit:
on more digging you might be searching for `-webkit-tap-highlight-color`, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11885330/4035369)

Comment: Thank you! It was the -webkit-tap-highlight-color